# Mongodb find is working with bindata but $match is not working with bindata

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In mongodb query find with Bindata is working but while trying with match, it is not working

```
db.mytable.find({"myguid_field": new BinData(3,"Base64data==") }).limit(10);
```

I am getting proper result.

But in case of aggregate query with match is not working.

```
db.mytable.aggregate([ { $match : { myguid_field: { $eq: new BinData(3,'Base64data==') } } } ]);
```

The above query I am getting empty result

```
while db.mytable.aggregate([]);
```

gives result.

Could someone please help me regarding this?
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

its working ,
By mistake in case of match the field name has a capital letter